# How to remove selected drop down value in HTML using Java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a multiple dropdown item,
when i selected a item from a drop down, that item shouldn't show to another drop down.

For an example

drop downs

**drop town items are "10 20 30"**

initially ,

1st Dropdown contain "10, 20, 30"

2nd Dropdown contain "10, 20, 30"

3rd Dropdown contain "10, 20, 30"

**When i choose 30 from 2nd drop down and 1st and 3rd drop down shouldn't show "30" to both.**

I hope someone will help soon, Thanks in Advance
Below the code i tried

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    var hideOptions = function () {             
        var $select =  $('select');
        $select.find('option').show();
        $select.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var value = $this.val();
            var $options = $this.siblings('select').find('option');
            var $option = $options.filter('[value="' + value + '"]');
            if (value) {
                $option.hide();
                $option.each(function () {
                    if (this.defaultSelected) {
                        $(this).parent('select').val('');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    hideOptions();

    $('select').on('change', function () {  

        hideOptions();
    });
});
</script>



<table style="width:40%" class="requiredField">
<tbody><tr><th>File header</th><th>Table Column</th></tr>

<tr><td>EMAIL</td><td><select name="EMAIL">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="Email_Address">Email_Address</option>
<option value="Salutation">Salutation</option>
<option value="First_Name">First_Name</option>
<option value="Last_Name">Last_Name</option>
<option value="Gender">Gender</option>
<option value="Company">Company</option>
<option value="Country">Country</option></td></tr>

<tr><td>Salutation</td><td><select name="Salutation">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="Email_Address">Email_Address</option>
<option value="Salutation">Salutation</option>
<option value="First_Name">First_Name</option>
<option value="Last_Name">Last_Name</option>
<option value="Gender">Gender</option>
<option value="Company">Company</option>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Do you want value of one selected drop-down to be reflected on other two?

Comment: @bunty yes i wanna affect and shouldn't show selected value from other drop down

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.drop').on('change', 'select', function() {
    // For all `select` inside `.drop`

        $(this).siblings('select').find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove();

        // Get other `select` and remove the selected option from other select
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/2wopf23v/1/

Comment: Team2 selected team3 and Team3 selected Team1 So that Team 1 should contain Team2 only not all.

Comment: Selected dropdown value changed.
I need dynamically select and unselect the dropdown. Also unselected vaules from whole values only comes in other dropdown. 

Selected dropdown value changed after make this below the steps.
select the dropdownA->Company into Email_Address
select dropdownB->Company
Now we can see the dropdownA values are changed. But i am choosed Email_Address in dropdownA.

Please correct me if where i am wrong.
Here demo..
http://jsfiddle.net/ramalingam07/q8fcrxy9/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script `src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.team1').live('change', function() {
    var allteam = $('.team1').html();
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('.team1[id!="' + $(this).attr("id") + '"]').each(function() {
        $(this).find('option[value="' + val + '"]').remove();
    }); 
    //alert("allteam " + allteam);
}); 
</script> 
<div class="drop">
Team:1
<select data-placeholder="Select Team 1" class="chzn-select team1 drop" tabindex="6" name="team1[]" id="team_one">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Team one">Team one</option>
    <option value="Team two">Team two</option>
    <option value="Team three">Team three</option>
</select>
Team:2
<select data-placeholder="Select Team 2" class="chzn-select team1 drop" tabindex="6" name="team1[]"  id="team_two">
    <option value="">Select </option>
    <option value="Team one">Team one</option>
    <option value="Team two">Team two</option>
    <option value="Team three" selected>Team three</option>
</select>
Team:3
<select data-placeholder="Select Team 2" class="chzn-select team1" tabindex="6" name="team1[]"  id="team_three">
    <option value="">Select </option>
    <option value="Team one" selected>Team one</option>
    <option value="Team two">Team two</option>
    <option value="Team three">Team three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i have update the code in my post. And more that 30 dropdown fields are here.

Comment: Can you just elaborate it? I didnt get it

Comment: Selected dropdown value changed.
I need dynamically select and unselect the dropdown. Also unselected vaules from whole values only comes in other dropdown. 

Selected dropdown value changed after make this below the steps.
select the dropdownA->Company into Email_Address
select dropdownB->Company
Now we can see the dropdownA values are changed. But i am choosed Email_Address in dropdownA.

Please correct me if where i am wrong.
Here demo..
http://jsfiddle.net/ramalingam07/q8fcrxy9/

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.team1').change(function() {
      var allteam = $('.team1').val();
      item2(allteam);
    });

    function item2(all1) {
      $name = all1;
      $(".team2 option").each(function() {
       if(this.value == $name){
         $(this).hide();
       }
      });
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drop">
  Team:1
  <select data-placeholder="Select Team 1" class="chzn-select team1 drop" tabindex="6" name="team1[]">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Team one">Team one</option>
    <option value="Team two">Team two</option>
    <option value="Team three">Team three</option>
  </select>
  Team:2
  <select data-placeholder="Select Team 2" class="chzn-select team2 drop" tabindex="6" name="team1[]">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Team one">Team one</option>
    <option value="Team two">Team two</option>
    <option value="Team three" selected>Team three</option>
  </select>
  Team:3
  <select data-placeholder="Select Team 2" class="chzn-select team3" tabindex="6" name="team1[]">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Team one" selected>Team one</option>
    <option value="Team two">Team two</option>
    <option value="Team three">Team three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

you can do this way to another third one

Comment: Team 1: should not contain Team three and team one Because it's already selected

Comment: i can not understand what you want to say plz little bit more explain what you want to say

Comment: Selected dropdown value changed.
I need dynamically select and unselect the dropdown. Also unselected vaules from whole values only comes in other dropdown. 

Selected dropdown value changed after make this below the steps.
select the dropdownA->Company into Email_Address
select dropdownB->Company
Now we can see the dropdownA values are changed. But i am choosed Email_Address in dropdownA.

Please correct me if where i am wrong.
Here demo..
http://jsfiddle.net/ramalingam07/q8fcrxy9/

Comment: Have a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/q8fcrxy9/6/ 
I have updated the code. I have just added one condition in hideOptions function before resetting the select value

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to regain the removed (in this case, the hidden) options when they get unselected:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var hideOptions = function () {
        var $select =  $('select');
        $select.find('option').show();
        $select.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var value = $this.val();
            var $options = $this.siblings('select').find('option');
            var $option = $options.filter('[value="' + value + '"]');
            if (value) {
                $option.hide();
                $option.each(function () {
                    if (this.defaultSelected) {
                        $(this).parent('select').val('');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    hideOptions();

    $('select').on('change', function () {
        hideOptions();
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qemy9wdh/)**

**Update:**

With the provide HTML-Markup you have to change the the line which set the varibale `$options` to:

```
var $options = $this.parents('table').find('select').not(this).find('option');
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/qemy9wdh/1/)**

Comment: Fine But Team 1: should not contain Team three and team one. Because it's already selected.

Comment: Thanks! but i am try this table format select option. It's not run correctly.Please correct me if i have any error.the code is :

Comment: i have update the code in my post. the example of dropdown EMAIL and Salutation, And more that 30 dropdown fields are here.Coorect me if i have any error

Comment: @RamaLingam I edited my answer and included a second example. If you want to specify which `select`-fields are getting found, just modify the selecor of `.find('select')`

Comment: Selected dropdown value changed.
I need dynamically select and unselect the dropdown. Also unselected vaules from whole values only comes in other dropdown. 

Selected dropdown value changed after make this below the steps.
select the dropdownA->Company into Email_Address
select dropdownB->Company
Now we can see the dropdownA values are changed. But i am choosed Email_Address in dropdownA.

Comment: Please correct me if where i am wrong.
Here demo..
http://jsfiddle.net/ramalingam07/q8fcrxy9/

Answer (score 0):

This is a jquery code I made which does exactly this. Also leaves empty values in (if you have "Please select" in the top) and reinserts unselected values. It does it for all select elements on the page, if you need to restrict replace the selector $("select") with a more specific one:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  manageSelectValues();
  $("select").change(manageSelectValues); 
});

function manageSelectValues()
{
  $("select").each(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var value = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    if (value) {
      $("select[id!='" + id + "']").find("option").filter(function() { return this.value == value;}).remove();
    }
    $(this).find("option").filter(function() { return this.value != value;}).each(function() {
      var unselValue = $(this).val();
      $("select").filter(function() { return $(this).find("option").filter(function() { return this.value == unselValue;}).length == 0; }).append(
        $('<option></option>').val(unselValue).html(unselValue));
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Selected dropdown value changed.
I need dynamically select and unselect the dropdown. Also unselected vaules from whole values only comes in other dropdown. 

Selected dropdown value changed after make this below the steps.
select the dropdownA->Company into Email_Address
select dropdownB->Company
Now we can see the dropdownA values are changed. But i am choosed Email_Address in dropdownA.

Please correct me if where i am wrong.
Here demo..
http://jsfiddle.net/ramalingam07/q8fcrxy9/

Comment: The problem is you don't have an id in your select elements. Add the id attribute with same value as the name or modify the script to use name instead on id.

That is if you want to use the script above.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get your code running by removing `selected` from your table. so the code looks like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

var hideOptions = function () {
    var $select = $('select');
    $select.find('option').show();
    $select.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var value = $this.val();
        var $options = $this.parents('table').find('select').not(this).find('option');
        var $option = $options.filter('[value="' + value + '"]');
        if (value) {
            $option.hide();
            $option.each(function () {
                if (this.defaultSelected) {
                    $(this).parent('select').val('');
                }
            });
        }
    });
};

hideOptions();

$('select').on('change', function () {
    hideOptions();
});
});
</script> 

<table style="width:40%" class="requiredField">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Mapping</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>dropdownA</td>
        <td>
            <select name="email">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="Email_Address">Email_Address</option>
                <option value="Salutation">Salutation</option>
                <option value="First_Name">First_Name</option>
                <option value="Last_Name">Last_Name</option>
                <option value="Gender">Gender</option>
                <option value="Company">Company</option>                    
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>dropdownB</td>
        <td>
            <select name="Salutation">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="Email_Address">Email_Address</option>
                <option value="Salutation">Salutation</option>
                <option value="First_Name">First_Name</option>
                <option value="Last_Name">Last_Name</option>
                <option value="Gender">Gender</option>
                <option value="Company">Company</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>       
     <tr>
        <td>dropdownC</td>
        <td>
            <select name="First_Name">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="Email_Address">Email_Address</option>
                <option value="Salutation">Salutation</option>
                <option value="First_Name">First_Name</option>
                <option value="Last_Name">Last_Name</option>
                <option value="Gender">Gender</option>
                <option value="Company">Company</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>dropdownD</td>
        <td>
            <select name="Last_Name">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="Email_Address">Email_Address</option>
                <option value="Salutation">Salutation</option>
                <option value="First_Name">First_Name</option>
                <option value="Last_Name">Last_Name</option>
                <option value="Gender">Gender</option>
                <option value="Company">Company</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>




</tbody>
```